# Magento 2.4.1: Class Magento\PageCache\Observer\SwitchPageCacheOnMaintenance does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

While running `php bin/magento maintenance:enable` after upgrading Magento to 2.4.1, I find the error message `Class Magento\PageCache\Observer\SwitchPageCacheOnMaintenance does not exist` How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observer class `SwitchPageCacheOnMaintenance` should not be exist on your  code `app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/events.xml`

This observer is removed for the reason `Unable to enable maintenance mode when env.php is read-only`  See Github issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24229 and PR `https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/commit/acd42b86af5425d799750f0ceb6c529cd17abba6#diff-7d28e4e5cde9c3dc49e562bbf8f1517313d78b8fe37e5fbcef1b55c9374d318f`

This issue happen bcoz of the upgrade does not run successfully

To remove this observer from your code.  Create an events.xml on your custom module and this module should events depends on `Magento_PageCache` from module.xml

**events.xml code should be:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="maintenance_mode_changed">
        <observer name="page_cache_switcher_for_maintenance"
                  disabled="true" />
    </event>
</config>
```

using `disabled="true"` code you can disabled an observer.